# spring ConfigurationProperties back compatibility

Tags: spring-boot

I have a project with bean with properties *a.b.prefix1.property1*, *a.b.prefix2.property2*, *a.b.prefix3.property3*. So I create property class

```
@ConfigurationProperties("a.b")
public class MyBeanProperties {

  @NotNull
  private String prefix1Property1;

  @NotNull
  private String prefix2Property2;

  @NotNull
  private String prefix3Property3;
}
```

But it doesn't work with points, because Relax Converter can convert properties only to *prefix1-property1* or *prefix1_property1* or *prefix1Property1* style. I can't change my properties'. Is there any way I can extent Relax Converter to let Spring read my old properties into this class *MyBeanProperties*?

Answer (score 0):

You may give up using ConfigurationProperties and use plain

```
public class public class MyBeanProperties {
    @Value("${a.b.prefix1.property1}")
    private String prefix1Property1;

    @Value("${a.b.prefix2.property2}")
    private String prefix2Property2;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inner classes

```
@ConfigurationProperties("a.b")
public class MyBeanProperties {

  @NotNull @Valid
  private Prefix1 prefix1;

  public static class Prefix1 {
    @NotNull
    private Property1 property1;
  }
```

}